# KVM NIC where can I see the eth number ?

Tags: kvm-virtualization, debian-squeeze

I added a NIC to a vm in kvm, but I tried "uping" eth0 to 3 but every time I get an error :

```
ERROR while getting interfaces flag : no such device
```

Where can I see the correct eth number / connected NIC's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably in the log. Do an `grep -F eth /var/log/syslog` and see the lines with eth.

Other possibility is to view `/proc/self/net/dev` which should contain all available devices in the first column.

Comment: thanks! any chance you also know how if there is a way to change the number of the NIC from eth5 to eth0 ?

Comment: Sure I know. But I can't get reputation for it :-). Look here `/etc/udev/rules.d/z25_persistent-net.rules`